# Suppose that p(x) is a monic 6-th degree polyonomial over R such that 1, i and 1 + 2i are roots and p(0) = 1. Find p(x).

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that p(x) is a monic 6-th degree polyonomial over R such that
1, i and 1 + 2i are roots and p(0) = 1. Find p(x). (Express your answer as a
polynomial in factored form over R.)

Comment: I know that ($x-1$), ($x^2+1$), and ($x^2-2x+5$) are factors from the Factor Theorem and conjugate pairs

Comment: So, multiply the polynomial you already have calculated with $x-u$ and choose $u$, such that $p(0)=1$ holds.

Comment: Is it as easy as that? Just multiplying what I have by ($x-1/5$)?

Comment: Yes, that is all.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Mondays.. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it is not as simple as that, You also need to prove that there are no other solutions, i.e. that your solution is unique.

Answer (score 0):

**HINTS:**

Assuming that your polynomial has real coefficients, we know that a complex number $z$ is a root if, and only if, the conjugate $\overline z$ is also a root. You should now know five of the roots, including the ones you gave in your question.

Remember that if $x=a$ and $x=b$ are roots of a quadratic then $x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$. [The $a$ and $b$ can be real, or complex]

You should now have one linear factor and two quadratic factors coming from $1$, $\mathrm i$ and $1+2\mathrm i$ being roots. This deals with five of the six degrees.

Write $p(x) = (x-k)(\mathrm{linear})(\mathrm{quadratic})(\mathrm{quadratic})$, where you know the linear factor and the two quadratic factors. Finally, use the fact that $p(0)=1$ to find $k$.